# Разрешение зависимостей для орграфа с циклами

Tags: графы, зависимости, компиляция

Балуюсь, хочу сделать транслятор из BNF в код-грамматику для [LEPL](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/). Парсер написал, код для отдельных правил генерируется, но дальше подзастрял с порядком правил.

Есть набор правил, ссылающихся друг на друга. Зависимости можно просто представить в виде орграфа, в котором *есть* циклы:

[image: Пример графа зависимостей]

Нужно разрешить зависимости относительно заданной вершины, получив список, в котором следует записывать правила так, чтобы последующие правила уже «видели» все требуемые им предыдущие. Если возникает цикл — нужно перед первым употреблением поместить «предварительную декларацию.» Т.е., для примера графа выше, если, упрощая, считать, что вершины содержат просто строки, получить что-то в духе:

```
>>> deps_dict = {
...    "A": {"B", "C"},
...    "B": {"D", "E"},
...    "C": {"A", "E"},
...    "E": {"E", "D"}
... }
>>> resolve_deps(deps_dict, "A")
[
    "D"              # {}
    Predeclare("E"), # ref'd by {E, B}
    "E"              # {D, E}
    "B"              # {D, E}
    Predeclare("A"), # ref'd by {C}
    "C"              # {A, E}
    "A"              # {B, C}
]
```

(То, что это не единственный вариант удовлетворяющего условиям результата — понятно.)

Положение в списке предварительных деклараций не очень важно — в худшем случае, можно их вытащить наверх, хотя лично мне хочется размещать их не раньше самого необходимого (т.е. перед первой отсылкой).

Если бы циклов не было — все было бы, вроде как, понятно — про топологическую сортировку я нашел и почитал. Но как справиться с циклами — честно говоря, пока не соображу.

Comment: Почаще бы такие вопросы, а не вопросы типа [**Ошибка вывода капчи.**][1]

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/115723/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%87%D0%B8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Поскольку `БНФ` оперирует [*контекстно-свободными грамматиками,*](http://www.lsv.uni-saarland.de/Vorlesung/finite_state_transducers/ss09/lectures/2009-06-08/beamer-lecture.pdf) то самое простое - это использовать соответствующий раздел теории синтаксического анализа.
- Самое неприятное, что может быть в произвольно взятой `КС-грамматике G` - это [*левая рекурсия,*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) которая, нестрого говоря, делает грамматику `G` недетерминированной.

> - При этом шаги алгоритма избавления от левой рекурсии **включают в себя избавление от циклов.** Поскольку вы, судя по всему, пытаетесь достичь детерминированности соответствующей грамматики, то лично я рекомендовал бы сразу же заимплементировать алгоритм избавления от левой рекурсии.

- Простое описание подхода избавления от левой рекурсии можно найти [**здесь,**](http://www.d.umn.edu/~hudson/5641/l11m.pdf) более же обзорная публикация по разным алгоритмам избавления от левой рекурсии расположена [**тут.**](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/68869/naacl2k-proc-rev.pdf)

> - Если вы действительно знаете, что делаете и хотите *только избавиться от циклов,* то воспользуйтесь только шагами `(1)` и `(2)` из публикации `Eliminating left-recursion: three steps`.

- Из дополнительных референсов могу порекомендовать пост *Эрика Липперта* по поводу [**`CFG` и циклов в них вообще,**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530275/recursive-string-replacement-in-c-sharp) а также [**набор хороших презентаций**](http://gas-teach.narod.ru/au/tfl/tfl06.pdf) по теории формальных языков.

Comment: Ммм... А если без преобразований грамматики? LEPL сам по себе умеет разбираться с циклами и LR. Вот если «не взлетит» — тогда да.

Т.е. имея BNF:

    <equation> ::= <term> = <term>
    <term> ::= 1 | <addition>
    <addition> ::= <term> + <term>

Я, не трогая правил, для начала, думаю просто преобразовать синтаксис:

    TERM = Delayed()
    ADDITION = TERM & Literal("+") & TERM
    TERM += Literal("1") | ADDITION
    EQUATION = TERM & Literal("=") & TERM

И, сделав, `EQUATION &= Eos(); EQUATION.config.auto_memoize()` пусть работает.

Или такой подход слишком порочен и лучше так не делать?